# c# passing parameter value from win app to another win app

Tags: c#

I have problem
i need to pass parameter value from my win app to another win app in c#.

**Is this possible؟؟**

**how ?**

Does the program require the use of port ?

please help me

Comment: You are talking about web services.

Comment: @jmc, that's one of a great many possible solutions, from shared memory, shared files, pipes, ports, windows messaging etc all the way up to complex soap-based web service communications.

Comment: solution will depend on distance between two win apps, e.g. localhost, intranet or internet

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go for inter process communication to communicate between 2 different applications.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

Communicating via windows messages example

http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx